# Get base URL in Yii console application

Tags: php, yii, console-application, yii1.x

How to get base URL in a Yii `CConsoleApplication` application?

I tried `Yii::app()->request->getBaseUrl(true)` and ended up with the following error.

> Undefined index: SERVER_NAME (/var/www/yii/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php:279)

Comment: URL in console? Can you give an example of desired result?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no request object in a console application. the request object in a web application its an instance of [CHttpRequest](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest), if you are generating URLs in an offline task, you have to configure the baseUrl in some other way, perhaps in the configuration:

```
"request" => array(
    'hostInfo' => 'http://localhost',
    'baseUrl' => '/yii-project/index-test.php',
),

// OR

'request' => array(
    'hostInfo' => 'http://localhost',
    'baseUrl' => '/yii-project',
    'scriptUrl' => 'index-test.php',
),
```

Comment: Thanks, Where should I place this?

Comment: this should go into your console configuration file, in the components section, that is normally protected/config/console.php

Comment: get error on trying to set hostInfo `Property "CConsoleApplication.request" is read only.`

Comment: @user1954544 you should to put in inside "components" array, to into a root config;

Answer (score 4):

For Yii2 advanced template, create `params.php` file if it doesn't exist in `config` directory of your console or common app and paste the following code:

```
return [
   'frontendUrl' => 'http://yourdomain.com'
];
```

So that it can be accessed in the following way in console:

```
echo Yii::$app->params['frontendUrl'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add in config/console.php in components array

```
'request' => array(
    'hostInfo' => 'http://localhost',
    'baseUrl' => '',
    'scriptUrl' => '',
),
```

and also add urlManager so it will remove index.php?r=site/action from the url and you will have pretty urls

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => array(
        '<controller:\w+>' => '<controller>/index',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

Answer (score -3):

Please try the following wayt to get the base url page,

```
echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true);
```

Comment: How is application base bath in file system related to a base URL?

Comment: It returns base path not base url.

Comment: This works on Web Application, but not in a Console Application.

Comment: Please don't put -ve without proper testing , its working code

Comment: Great Elby. Can i have your mail id please? i would like to have contact.

Answer (score -3):

get the home url like this:

http://www.demo.local

```
echo Yii::app()->homeUrl;
```